# How to use Ghostscript for converting PDF to Image

Tags: c#, image, pdf, ghostscript

I found that Ghostscript is able to convert PDF to Image format.

I tried [PDF to Image Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API) but not able to understand it clearly.

I have installed `gs905w64.exe` but when I tried to `add reference` to my web application I am getting this error.

`A reference to gsdll32.dll could not be added. No type libraries were found in the component.`

Comment: I wish you luck with your question, but I feel it is a responsibility of people here to discourage any question askers from using the phrase "still not working", in response to an answer, without giving details as to what is happening. This prompts the helper to ask for more detail as to _what was expected_ and _what actually happened_. Be detailed in your responses, for every question `:)`. -1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use C# to run the GhostScript command line or use Platform Invoke (pInvoke) calls to call the GhostScript dll directly.

GhostScript is primarily file based, so the input is path to a file on disk and the output is the creation of files on disk. The parameters used to call either the dll or exe are basically the same, so there is not a huge benefit to calling the dll directly, but does make for nicer code.

I have C# wrapper that can be used to call the ghostscript dll, if you email me (address on profile) I will sent it to you.

HTH

UPDATE:

code repo moved to https://bitbucket.org/brightertools/ghostscript

Comment: Hi Mark Redman, 
Could you please let me know some example of gsdll32.dll which can convert pdf files to images?
Is it possible to convert each and every pages to images ?

This is my email id "y.surendar@yahoo.in"
Thanks

Comment: @Sky5005e: Sent you an email.

Comment: Hi Mark, I didn't found any attachment on that email. 
Please try again
Thanks

Comment: @MarkRedman Send me the source plase...my email is umairprivacy@gmail.com

Answer (score 10):

You Do not need to add any DLL reference  to your project.
First download the gs910w32.exe application file
then install it to your local computer.
Get the location of the installed .exe file 
eg:-

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.64\bin\gswin32.exe"

use it in your C# application as :

```
 
  private void PdfToJpg(string inputPDFFile, string outputImagesPath)
        {
            string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.64\bin\gswin32.exe";
            String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r102.4 -o" + outputImagesPath + "%d.jpg -sPAPERSIZE=a4 " + inputPDFFile;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
```

IF your input PDF file name has any spaces, you need to change the argument to

```
 
String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r102.4 -o" + outputImagesPath + "%d.jpg -sPAPERSIZE=a4 " +"\"" + inputPDFFile + "\"";
```

you can specify the output image's aspect ratio in the argument with the -r flag.
If you use "-r300" the width of the image will be 3000 pixel and height will change accordingly, from the above argument you will get 1024 to 768 size jpg image.

Comment: If you would like to have more control, I would suggest suggest you to use .NET Ghostscript wrapper like: http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com

Comment: yes,following article explain more about Ghostscript wrapper API. [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API)

Answer (score 6):

The `gsdll32.dll` file is *not* a managed .NET library. You can't reference it in your project. You have to include it in your project as "content" (menu: Add existing item) and let VS copy it to the output directory. Meanwhile you should read [the Ghostscript API docs](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/API.htm) and [this article on PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gsapi.gsapi_new_instance) on how to reference the Ghostscript functions.

Keep in mind that Ghostscript is all unmanaged code and that you have to do the clean-up yourself after using the library.

*Edit:* What Robert said is important, too. Of course, you have to use the correct version of the Ghostscript library.

Comment: Do you still get the error message mentioned in your question? Can you describe what you're trying to do and what exactly is not working?

Comment: Right now I am trying to run this application (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API?fid=1533292&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&tid=4190375) but it still asking to copy the `dll`..

Comment: It works fine now...but image quality is to bad..what to do with that..?

Comment: See the [Ghostscript documentation](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.05/Use.htm#Parameter_switches). There you will find some information about parameters you can use to increase resolution or enable interpolation. These parameters must be used with `gsapi_init_with_args`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you try to add the library as reference to your project? `gsdll32.dll` is a native dll, not a Dot-Net library.

When I build the sample project using Visual C# Express 2010 I get an exe file. If I execute it it tries to access the `gsdll32.dll`. The problem is now that on a 64bit system a 64bit executable is generated but the `gsdll32.dll` is compiled for 32bit.

The correct solution would be to modify the source code and replace `gsdll32.dll` with `gsdll64.dll` everywhere it occurs. The simpler solution is to use the 64 bit version of Ghostscript, copy the `gsdll64.dll` into the same directory as the `ConvertPDF.exe` and rename it to `gsdll32.dll`. This definitely works - just tested and converted a PDF to TIFF.

Comment: Ok..It works fine now...but image quality is to bad..what to do with that..?

Comment: Well that is the Ghostscript quality. Your question was only about how to make it run.

Comment: @user1530755: As for the 'image quality' question -- this can easily be resolved. Now that it does at last *run* on your system, just ask another question, and indicate what commandline options or equivalent c# code you use for your conversion...

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the below command to reference the library
http://www.nuget.org/packages/GhostScriptSharp/

VS2012 --> Tools --> Library Package Manager --> Package Manager Console