# Visual Studios 2015 NuGet Ghostscript Installation Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, ghostscript

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this installation error for `gsdll32`

I am running 64 bit windows and visual studios 2015. The only thing i can think of is that nuget is trying to install the 32 bit dll on the 64 bit version of visual studios. But i can't seem to confirm this error with anyone else. I need Ghostscript to convert PDFs to JPGs on a website. If you have an alternative to Ghostscript let me know. Visual studios installed Ghostscript.NET just fine. but it fails on ghostscript itself.

```
PM> Install-Package Ghostscript -Version 9.2.0
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' with respect to project 'wilcox_fresh', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 845.32 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0'
Retrieving package 'Ghostscript 9.2.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Neoaptt\Source\Repos\wilcoxfreshsite\packages'
Added package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Neoaptt\Source\Repos\wilcoxfreshsite\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' does not exist in project 'wilcox_fresh'
Removing package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' from folder 'C:\Users\Neoaptt\Source\Repos\wilcoxfreshsite\packages'
Removed package 'Ghostscript.9.2.0' from folder 'C:\Users\Neoaptt\Source\Repos\wilcoxfreshsite\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 460.6 ms
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'gsdll32'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Ghostscript -Version 9.2.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.4721036
```

Comment: Sometimes when reopening repos on new computers my nuget references get screwed up and I have to do update-package Ghostscript -reinstall .  Could that be the case here or is this just on a fresh project?

Comment: ghostscript never installed to begin with. It fails on installation.

Comment: If you want Ghostscript installed, I'd suggest you use the Windows installer, which is available from the ghostscript.com site (under downloads). Once installed, the DLLs will be available (along with everything else). Please be aware that Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL which covers its use for Software as a Service, just in case you are using this commercially. I just checked the NuGet package and it does not include the licence which is a clear AGPL violation. I'll arrange to contact the maintainer and discuss this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Visual Studios 2015 NuGet Ghostscript Installation Error

That because `gsdll32.dll` is a native dll, not a not a managed .NET library. So you could not install it in your project. You could download that package and include dll file into your project as "content" and set the value of properties "`Copy to Output Directory`" to "`Copy Always`".

You can refer to [How to use Ghostscript for converting PDF to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517659/how-to-use-ghostscript-for-converting-pdf-to-image) for more detail info about calling the GhostScript dll directly.

Besides, we could expect the next version of the Ghostscript package.