# Dynamically create .pdf file on server

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf

I need to retrieve and then display a pdf file. I have working code that retrieves an image from a database, converts to .pdf, and returns that as JSON. I can display this just fine in chrome by making it into a blob, but because IE refuses to support data URIs, I figure I could generate a temporary pdf file on the server and then link to it like this, as suggested elsewhere on the site:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame">
    <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

And then set the `src` attribute in .js file:

```
 $('#myFrame').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/tempPDFname.pdf');
```

How would I generate this file and make it available on server (C#) so I can set the `src` attribute?

Comment: That completely depends on how your server is built.  You just need to make an action / handler that serves a PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to return a PDF from a Web API application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042614/how-to-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-api-application)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("documents/{docid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Display(string docid) {
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
var documents = reader.GetDocument(docid);
if (documents != null && documents.Length == 1) {
    var document = documents[0];
    docid = document.docid;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    //generate pdf document
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    MyPDFGenerator.New().PrintToStream(document, memoryStream);
    //get buffer
    buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
    //content length for use in header
    var contentLength = buffer.Length;
    //200
    //successful
    var statuscode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response = Request.CreateResponse(statuscode);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(buffer));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=" + document.Name + ".pdf", out contentDisposition)) {
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }
} else {
    var statuscode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    var message = String.Format("Unable to find resource. Resource \"{0}\" may not exist.", docid);
    var responseData = responseDataFactory.CreateWithOnlyMetadata(statuscode, message);
    response = Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)responseData.meta.code, responseData);
}
return response;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"GhostScript" may help you. Please check the linkes [How to use Ghostscript for converting PDF to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517659/how-to-use-ghostscript-for-converting-pdf-to-image) and https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/